# Gradle Android plugin 0.14.4 not deploying in IntelliJ

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using IntelliJ 14.0.1 Ultimate. I have a new project with nothing special in it. I want to use the Android Gradle plugin version 0.14.4. However, when I try to deploy my application it just doesn't happen, with this in the log:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_i9505g-e3015da6
```

I can however deploy my apk to the device by running the `installDebug` gradle task wither from the commandline or from IntelliJ. If i change the plugin version to 0.13.0 it works as it should.

Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

P.S. Also, when i change from 0.14.4 to 0.13.0 it removes all my source file entries from `app.iml`, e.g.:

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
```

and I have to put them back in manually.